# Eigenvalues of a large matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I want to compute the eigenvalues (and later the corresponding eigenvectors) of an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix. For this I use `{evs, vecs} = Eigensystem[matrix]` or the command `Eigenvalues` to evaluate only the eigenvalues, but this takes a long time when I already do it for a $40\times 40$ matrix, and that 30 times (I am computing energy bands and thus need to iterate the operation quite some times.)

How can I boost it to bigger matrices (time wise)?

Thanks!

Comment: Impossible to say without a representative example. Can even make it smaller, so long as it captures the class of matrices under consideration (numeric, symbolic, some mix,...?)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau If the OP has version 10.2 this could be related to an actual bug - see the answer by aeolus below.

Answer (score 8):

You **can** in fact use *Mathematica* for rather large eigenvalue problems if they have floating-point entries.

Here is a band-structure calculation in one dimension where the eigensystem of a $40\times 40$ matrix is computed 81 times (at different wave numbers):

```
h[u_, k_, dim_] := N[
  DiagonalMatrix[(k + Range[-dim, dim])^2]
   + Table[u[j - n], {j, -dim, dim}, {n, -dim, dim}]]

bands[u_, k_, dim_, n_] := 
 Module[{hamil, max, eigenvalues, eigenvectors},
  hamil = h[u, k, dim];
  max = Norm[Flatten[hamil]];
  {eigenvalues, eigenvectors} =
   Eigensystem[hamil - max IdentityMatrix[2 dim + 1], n];
  {eigenvalues + max, eigenvectors}
  ]

Clear[potential];
potential[n_] := 1/(n^2 + 1);

l = Table[First[bands[potential, k, 40, 4]], {k, -1, 1, .025}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[l], DataRange -> {-1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"k", "ℰ"}]
```

[image: bands]

It doesn't take more than about a second to do this calculation.

The important thing is to wrap the matrix in a command such as `N` so that the entries are machine-precision numbers that can be handled by the MKL numerical library. Depending on the origin of the matrix, it could also help to wrap the matrix in `SparseArray` before doing the eigenvalue computation.

To describe the specific example here: `potential` is the Fourier amplitude of a periodic potential, and `h` uses it as input to construct the hermitian matrix corresponding to the Hamiltonian in Fourier space. This is then diagonalized with the command `bands` for a specific value of the wave number `k`. The dimension of the matrix returned by `h` can be specified in the third argument (`dim`) of `h`.

Answer (score 4):

I was actually trying to solve the same sort of problem with *Mathematica*. 
As of 10.2, the `Eigensystem` function has a bug that will revert to using dense matrices even when fed sparse matrices.

You may want to consider using MATLAB until this is fixed. (Hopefully in 10.3!I will update when I get confirmation.)

Source: email correspondence with Wolfram Support.

Comment: Thanks for this warning - I just answered but have version 10.1.

Comment: I actually encountered the problem in 10.1 as well, but was wrapping/using only sparse matricies 100sX100s in dimension. I never tried wrapping in N[] though... maybe worth a shot. Your implementation seems to work well and fast regardless! Up!

Comment: Oh, OK - good to know. I heard 10.3 is just around the corner, so let's hope for a happy end. I guess I'll remove the caveat from my answer since it *should* work.

Comment: Is that bug fixed in the current version?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've kinda moved to Jupyter/Python since this. I'll try to check soon!

Answer (score -4):

Generally working with large matrix needs large amount of RAM and Mathematica is not a good choice for this kind of problems. Using linear algebra libraries like LAPACK and MKL can be very efficient and easy. There is a good example and clear explanation [here](https://source.ggy.bris.ac.uk/wiki/LinAlgebraPacks).

Comment: ...if the matrix has numeric entries. Of note is that *Mathematica* actually uses LAPACK under the hood for most linear algebraic operations.

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88349/193

Comment: I fail to see any relevance here. For matrices of machine doubles Mathematica uses a storage format pretty much as condensed as any other, and uses Lapack and MKL libraries. This is not exactly a secret.