# Why has Version 10.3 precision reduced?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, precision-and-accuracy

In version 7.0.1.0 and versions 10.0 and 10.1 the following is produced:

```
{u, w, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[{{3., 7.}, {2., 13.}}];
InputForm /@ (u.w.Transpose[v])
```

> {{3.000000000000001, 7.000000000000001}, {2., 13.000000000000002}}

In versions 10.3 and 10.3.1 the precision has reduced:

> {{3.0000000000000018, 7.000000000000002}, {2.0000000000000018, 
>     13.000000000000004}}

This result is happening on Windows 7 and 10.  Does anyone know why this is happening and is there something I can change to get the former result on version 10.3.1?  I'm concerned this may also be affecting optimisation results.

Comment: Could be a bug/difference in MKL, if the version changed between 10.1 and 10.3. I don't know if it did, but you can check that.

Comment: Thanks. According to this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88349/363) there was a change.  Mma 10.1 uses MKL 11.2.1 and Mma 10.3 uses MKL 11.2.2.  Not a major version change though.

Comment: In Mathematica 10.4.1 the original higher precision result is obtained. The MKL library version is 11.3.1.1

Comment: My Windows 10 installation of Mma 10.4.0 produces the second answer.  My Mac on 10.4.1 produces the first.  Wolfram support ran it on Win 7 on several version up to 10.3.1 all producing the first answer.  They suggested a [clean start](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464) or reinstallation.  I saw another Windows 10.4.0 produce the first answer, so it doesn't seem to be the MKL.  I tried a clean start to no avail.