# A simple question: Input problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

I have a simple problem. First I define the value of variables, then I calculate the expression as the following:

Code 1:

```
a = 10^-6; 
b = 10^-3;
c = 1;
d = 0.1;
s = -d Sqrt[b^2 + c^2];

Integrate[(w E^(-w/a))/(w - s), {w, 0, ∞}]
-3.744368975478385*10^43415
```

As you see the result is so large. But if I manually insert the value of s (-0.1) into the expression, I would get zero, which is is close to the correct answer:

Code 2:

```
a = 10^-6; 
b = 10^-3;
c = 1;
d = 0.1;
s = -d Sqrt[b^2 + c^2];

Integrate[(w E^(-w/a))/(w + 0.1), {w, 0, ∞}]
0.
```

What is the problem with the first code?

Comment: Have you tried using exact numbers instead of approximate ones? In other words, does the result of your first calculation change if you set `d = 1/10` instead? Also, the exact value of `s` is very close to $-0.1$, but not *exactly equal* to that value. Why do you think yours is a valid substitution?

Comment: Yes. If I use  d=1/10  instead, the result would be different. It is strange, because the result is 9.99979*10^-12, not zero as code 2. I know that 0.1 is different from 1/10, but it is improbable that their difference leads to a number of the order of 10^43415 (code 1). Moreover, I substitute the mathematica value of s into code 2. I still don't understand why the result of definition (code 1) is very different from the result of manual substitution (code 2).

Comment: But the numerical zero does not have to be the right answer. The number you get for d = 1/10 is fine. In code 2 may be the integration to infinity gets a different value for s=-0.1, which is not the number for d=1/10 (as already pointed out by MarcoB).

Comment: While the handling of inexact input by *Mathematica's* exact solvers has improved recently, I feel one should still use caution when doing it.  Use `NIntegrate`, or if possible, solve exactly before plugging in inexact parameters (e.g., this works in the present case `Block[{s}, Integrate[(w E^(-w/a))/(w - s), {w, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> s < 0]]`).

Answer (score 2):

In your inputs

```
a = 10^-6; 
b = 10^-3;
c = 1;
d = 0.1;
s = -d Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]
```

> -0.1

this result is approximated for display.  You can see the complete result by placing your cursor in front of the `-0.1` and pressing the space bar.

Alternatively

```
InputForm[s]
```

> -0.1000000499999875

***Edit***

With `s = -d Sqrt[b^2 + c^2]` the integral calculation yields ...

in Mathematica 7.0.1.0 : `9.99979500615538*10^-12`

in Mathematica 10.3.1 : `-3.744368975619640*10^43415`

Comment: Yes. That 's right. But this tiny difference would result in a difference of the order of 10^43415 in the final result?

Comment: In Mathematica 7.0.1.0 the result is `9.99979500615538*10^-12`.  However, with `s = -0.1` the result is `9.999800005898997*10^-12` which is `4.99974*10^-18` more.

Comment: No. For d=0.1, I get  -3.7*10^43415. Strangely, for d=1/10, I get your result, which is 9.9998*10^-12. Why such a difference in the result?

Comment: On Mathematica 10.3.1 the result is `-3.744368975619640*10^43415` but not on Mathematica 7.0.1.0 (both running on Windows 10).

Comment: @ChirsDegnen Thanks. I have a bunch of expressions. I can't substitute the variables manually. It seems that I should go to Mathematica 7.

Comment: It might be something to do with the Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL) in which case you'd only need to go back to Mathematica 10.1 to get a different version.  See this post: [Why has Version 10.3 precision reduced?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104545/why-has-version-10-3-precision-reduced) also the post referenced there.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up what we have been saying in comments, it may sometimes be dangerous to use symbolic solvers (e.g. `Integrate`) with inexact input (e.g. $d=0.1$). It is better in your case to evaluate the integral symbolically, and then calculate the approximate numerical value:

```
a = 10^-6;
b = 10^-3;
c = 1;
s = -d Sqrt[b^2 + c^2];
d = 1/10;

Integrate[(w E^(-w/a))/(w - s), {w, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N[%]
(* Out: 9.99979*10^-12 *)
```

The result is of course very close to zero, *but not exactly zero*. The problem doesn't lie in how close $s$ is to $-0.1$, but in whether you use exact or approximate input to `Integrate`, which the function does not handle gracefully in this case.

Comment: +1 Also works with `NIntegrate[(w E^(-w/a))/(w - s), {w, 0, Infinity}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]
`