# Why doesn't 'Abort evaluation' properly work when NotebookEvaluate is executed?

Tags: bugs, front-end, evaluation, notebooks

The following procedure can be easily aborted using Evaluation > Abort Evaluation menu item:

```
Do[j + k, {j, 1, 10000}, {k, 1, 10000}]
```

But it is not possible if `NotebookEvaluate` was used:

```
nb = CreateDocument[ ExpressionCell[Defer[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]], "Input"]]
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True];
```

Now run this again:

```
Do[j+k,{j,1,10000},{k,1,10000}]
```

and try to abort. It does not work and the loop is on.

Anyone knows why? Is there any alternative to `NotebookEvaluate`?

Comment: I rephrased the question and made the example self contained. Feel free to revert my changes. p.s. +1, interesting.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! Your rephrase seems great!

Comment: WRI says it is a 'known issue' so I guess [tag:bugs] applies.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find this workaround, I know not what it does.

```
In[1]:= Pause[3];(*abortable*)

Out[1]= $Aborted

In[2]:= Quiet@NotebookEvaluate@"abc";

In[3]:= Pause[3];(*unabortable*)

In[4]:= MathLink`LinkAddInterruptMessageHandler[$ParentLink]

In[5]:= Pause[3];(*Aborts are back!*)

Out[5]= $Aborted
```

Comment: Thanks for this strange but functioning workaround!

Answer (score 2):

I found this clunky workaround:

```
file = NotebookOpen[filename];
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[file, "SelectAll"]]
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[file, "Evaluate"]]
```

Comment: It should be noted that this workaround behaves very differently to `NotebookEvaluate` in a few aspects: `NotebookEvaluate` evaluates the notebook and waits until it is done, while your method simply enqueues it for evaluation. (Also, the line numbers are different)