# If I use NotebookEvaluate, then I can't abort a While loop

Tags: bugs, notebooks, abort

I have a notebook `Main.nb`.   This notebook contains a `While[...]` loop that takes about twelve hours  to run.    I have a second notebook called `DataPreparation.nb`. As the name suggests, the contents of `DataPreparation.nb` should be evaluated before the `While[...]` loop mentioned  above.

Scenario 1 (with no bug):

1. From `DataPreparation.nb` notebook, `Select All` and `Evaluate`.
2. Switch to `Main.nb` notebook and start evaluation  of `While[]` loop.
3. If I need to abort the twelve hour  `While[]` loop, I use `Alt+.` and it promptly
   stops.    Good.

Scenario 2 (with the bug)

1. From `Main.nb`,  I invoke this command:`NotebookEvaluate["DataPreparation.nb", InsertResults -> False]`.
2. Start evaluation of  `While[]` loop.
3. If I need to abort the twelve hour `While[]` loop, I use `Alt+.` The abort command is ignored.
4. To abort the twelve hour process, I must quit Kernel.  I lose my work.

It appears that after I have used `NotebookEvaluate`, Mathematica loses  track of where the abort command should be directed.   I know that is an imprecise description of the problem,  but it is the best I can do.

ps. This question is different from the question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189744/why-doesnt-abort-evaluation-properly-work-when-notebookevaluate-is-executed?rq=1).  The difference is that in the earlier question, the loop which can not  be aborted is contained in `EvaluateNotebook[...]`.  In my case, I am simply calling `EvaluateNotebook[...]` .  The while  loop which can't be aborted is contained in the  main notebook.

Comment: Strange. Something as simple as ```t = 0;While[t < 100000000, t++]``` in notebook T can easily be aborted. But if you create two different notebooks A and B, where A contains only something like ```x=7+2``` and B calls NotebookEvaluate on A, then the While operation in notebook T cannot be aborted.

Comment: Thanks @Jean for confirming my observation.  It is easy to avoid using NotebookEvaluate.   I was just wondering if someone can explain what is  going on.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the other question you linked.  It is indeed the same issue.  In that question, the `Do` loop which can't be aborted is in the same notebook from which the `NotebookEvaluate` was called, just like here.

Comment: @Jason.   I guess you are right. I did misinterpret that other question.  If you think I must, I will delete this question.

Comment: Leave it open so future searchers can find it, but you can close it as a duplicate.  Can you check if the workaround I posted there works for you?

Comment: @Jason I will try that workaround later today and post results here.  I'm expecting it will work, but I have no experience with "FrontEndExecute" or "FrontEndToken".  Still,  it  should be easy to cut and paste when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Not that workaround, which basically avoids calling `NotebookEvaluate`.  The one I just posted, which just means calling ```MathLink`LinkAddInterruptMessageHandler[$ParentLink] ``` directly after calling `NotebookEvaluate`.

Comment: @Jason  RE: MathLink`LinkAddInterruptMessageHandler[$ParentLink]      Yes, that workaround seems to work.  Thanks.  Maybe you can figure out what is happening and post  a full answer here.

Comment: @Jason Yes this restores the aborts, but it is not related to NotebookEvaluate being in the same or a different notebook, as indicated in the example I provided earlier. Opening a new notebook  to enter the MathLink line restores the abort in my notebook T.

Comment: Does this rise to the level of a bug?

Comment: @Chris - this is a bug for sure, it's also a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @MarcoB  Please see discussion in comments.